# Unit Test a Method That Has Retry Logic

Tags: java, testng, jmockit

I have a method with retry logic. The retry logic is implemented using a customized annotation. I want a unit test that verifies that the method is called again upon a certain exception being thrown.

```
public class FileTest {

    String first;
    String second;
    Instant third;
    int fourth;

    @Tested
    StoreFiles storeFiles;

    @Injectable
    FileSystemFactory fileSystemFactory;

    @Mocked
    OracleConnection conn;

    @Before public void initMocks() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(StoreFiles.class);
    }

    @BeforeClass()
    public void init() {
        first= "test";
        second= "testRoot";
        third= Instant.now();
        fourth= 1;
    }

    @Test
    public void testRetry(@Mocked FileSystemFactory fileSystemFactory,
                          @Mocked StructDescriptor dbDataRecDesc,
                          @Mocked ArrayDescriptor dbDataTabDesc) throws CustomException {

        StoreFiles files = mock(StoreFiles.class);

        files.storeFiles(conn, first, second, third, fourth);

        Mockito.verify(files, times(2)).storeFiles(conn, first, second, third, fourth);
    }
}
```

Currently using jmockit, testng, and mockito. I just need to make sure the `storeFile` method is called again upon the `CustomException` being thrown. If I use the `storeFiles` object instead of `files` object, the exception that I want is thrown. If I run the test like it is written here I get an error that the `storeFiles` method was only called once, referring to where I explicitly call it in the test method. Both result in the method I'm testing not getting retried.

Answer (score 2):

That is hard to test because `StoreFiles::storeFile` method is doing 2 things: store file and executing retry logic. You could change your design to be more testable. This is my suggestion:

First, remove the retry logic from `StoreFiles::storeFile` and extract it to another class with that responsibility:

```
public class Retry {

    public void exec(Runnable r) {
        try {
            r.run();
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            r.run();
        }
    }

}
```

Now, you can write your retrying logic test like this:

```
public class RetryTest {

    //fields and init method

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Retry retry = new Retry();
        Mockito
            .doThrow(new CustomException()) //first StoreFiles::storeFile call, throws exeption
            .doNothing() //second StoreFiles::storeFile call, does nothing
            .when(storeFiles).storeFile(conn, first, second, third, fourth);

        retry.exec(() -> storeFiles.storeFile(conn, first, second, third, fourth));

        //verify StoreFiles::storeFile is called twice
        Mockito.verify(storeFiles, Mockito.times(2)).storeFile(conn, first, second, third, fourth);
    }

}
```

(I'm assuming CustomException is a non-checked exception)

Another solution is implementing decorator pattern and build a `RetryStoreFiles`:

```
public class RetryStoreFiles implements StoreFiles {

    private final StoreFiles decorated;

    public RetryStoreFiles(StoreFiles decorated) {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    @Override
    public void storeFile(conn: Conn, first: First, second: Second, third: Third, fourth: Fourth) {
        try {
            decorated.storeFile(conn, first, second, third, fourth);
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            decorated.storeFile(conn, first, second, third, fourth);
        }
    }

}
```

I like more this second solution. I think it's more semantic and object-oriented that the first one.

Comment: The only thing is is that the annotation for retrying a method is used throughout the application and refactoring where that is used would cause too much of a headache and take too much time to refactor and test.